# Chunked response in Node.js on Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-nodejs

I have some very simple Node.js code that I want to emit as chunked responses. The code is:

```
const WAIT = 500;
const records = [...];

function getList(req, res, url) {
    var list = records.slice().map(rec => JSON.stringify(rec) + "\n");
    var len = list.reduce((size, cur) => { size += Buffer.byteLength(cur); return size; }, 0);

    function next() {
        var cur = list.shift();
        if(!cur) {
            res.end();
            return;
        }

        res.write(cur);

        setTimeout(next, WAIT);
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-ndjson",
        "Content-Length": len.toString(),
        "X-Accel-Buffering": "no"
    });

    setTimeout(next, WAIT);
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
require("http").createServer(getList).listen(PORT);
```

This should write out this data as ndjson chunks until the array is emptied.

Locally and in a generic VPS this works as expected. On Heroku it does not emit the chunks in a streaming fashion, but rather dumps out them all at the end.

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your package.json?

Comment: Are you using compression? app.use(compression())?

Comment: @MaviDomates That's a really good thought and thanks for the suggestion. I'm not using compression, actually not even using Express or anything else at all. This is raw require("http").  But that's a good idea, so I checked the response headers anyways to see if Heroku was automatically compressing, but alas they are not.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that I have this running on a DigitalOcean VPS and the chunking is working; same exact code. So anything that's preventing the chunking must be something that Heroku is adding on top.

Comment: Well - I've tried :) Have you set your header to Tranfer-Encoding: chunked? I wonder if Digital Ocean is behaving smarter and picking that up where you need to specify for Heroku?

Comment: Transfer-Encoding did it!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Posted it as an answer and added some more info. I'd appreciate the green tick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments section - setting the `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` header explicitly resolved this problem. Digital Ocean might be doing something smart with chunking while you need to specify this explicitly in Heroku.

Documentation regarding the header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding

Another potential problem why this might occur in your system: https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/56 (If you're using an older version of expressjs - response flushing contained a bug)

Comment: Thank you so much.